# ¿Por qué decimos "presumir" y no "preasumir" para algo que asumimos preventivamente?

Tags: etimología, verbos

Siempre me ha sorprendido el doble uso del verbo *presumir*: tanto para *fardar* de algo como para indicar que creemos algo:

> A esa niña le gusta **presumir** de su pelo largo y brillante.
>
> **Presumo** que el examen me irá de pena.

Eso lo refleja el DLE:

> [**presumir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U7YygFe)
>   Del lat. praesumĕre.
>   1. tr. Suponer o considerar algo por los indicios o señales que se tienen. *Presumo que quiere conocerte en persona.*
>   2. intr. Mostrarse muy orgulloso de sí mismo o de sus cosas. *Presume DE ser el que más gana.*
>   3. intr. Preocuparse mucho del aspecto propio para parecer atractivo. *Cuida mucho su vestuario porque le encanta presumir.*

[Observo](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/presumedly) que *praesūmere* quiere decir "tomar por adelantado", pues junta *prae* → antes y *sūmere* → asumir.

Además, la primera acepción parece tener mucho que ver con:

> [**asumir**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=47S4L2q)
>   Del lat. assumĕre.
>   1. tr. Atraer a sí, tomar para sí.
>   2. tr. Hacerse cargo, responsabilizarse de algo, aceptarlo.
>   3. tr. Adquirir, tomar una forma mayor.

Y se observa cómo su raíz es común: *assumĕre* y *praesumĕre*. Entonces la pregunta que me surge automáticamente es: ¿por qué cayó esta "a" y no decimos *preasumir* o *praesumir*? ¿Se podría dar el caso que tuviéramos *presumir* por un lado y *preasumir* por el otro? Y ya que estamos: ¿cómo se explica la etimología de la 2.ª acepción de *presumir* en tanto en cuanto *urgulloso de sí mismo* y su relación con la "asunción"?

Comment: pre- + sumir; a- + sumir. El verbo original es *sumir*.

Comment: ad (towards) + sumere (take): assume / asumir # prae (before) + sumere (take): presume / presumir --- Note, "ad" and "prae" are the Latin prefixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los dos verbos derivan de la misma raíz, *sumere*, con dos prefijos diferentes, *ad-* (asimilado regularmente a *as-*) y *prae-*. *Sumere* a su vez es una fusión de *sub-* "bajo" y *emere* "tomar" (> *[sumir](http://dle.rae.es/?id=YheNXpa)* "hundir, sumergir").

*Presumir* tiene dos sentidos: el de "creer sin pruebas, presuponer" y el de "mostrarse orgulloso de algo". En latín *[praesumere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=praesumo&la=la&can=praesumo0&prior=praesumenter#lexicon)* ya tenía varios significados, entre ellos:

- tomar antes, tomar de antemano
- anticiparse (a hacer algo)
- anticipar, prever
- dar por sentado, creer, asumir
- confiar

Este último significado es más tardío que los primeros y se lo asocia a osadía o atrevimiento. No sería extraño que hubiera derivado por esa vía en el actual de "mostrarse orgulloso, hacer ostentación". Cuando uno confía ciegamente en su propia apariencia, *presume* de ella. Uno *presume* (de) algo que supone verdadero e indiscutible. Al presumir, se anticipa a lo que dirán los demás, cuya opinión es posterior a la propia confianza. La misma idea está presente en la expresión *ser (un/a) creído/a*, o también (al menos así decimos en Argentina) *creérsela*.

En cuanto a *asumir*, el prefijo *ad-* tiene el sentido de "atraer", que explica sus varios significados. Cuando un gobernante asume el poder, lo toma para sí.

No existe **preasumir*, pero bien podría construirse hoy en día para referirse, por ejemplo, a algún procedimiento legal anterior a la asunción del poder por parte de un gobernante.